# How to create Linear Regression line on a 2D scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I have one class of data from a bivariate normal distribution. This gives me 2 columns, and I plot it using

```
plot(Data_Class1).
```

Now I have another class of data from a different bivariate normal distribution. Again I have 2 columns and I overlay this plot using

```
points(Data_Class2).
```

Now I have to fit a linear regression line on this plot.

```
LinRegModel <- lm(Data_Class2 ~ DataClass1)
```

and `abline(LinRegModel)`.

This gives me a line alright but it uses only the first two of the 6 regression coefficients.

```
               [,1]      [,2]    
(Intercept)     0.88174   1.64518
Data_Class_11   0.02220   0.13223
Data_Class_12  -0.01948   0.13870
```

and is equal to doing `abline(0.88174,0.02220)`.

How can I use all 6 regression coeffiecients? Should I be using all 6 regression coefficients?

Comment: Looks like you're passing matrices (or data frames) in the formula, rather than the more usual y ~ x1 + x2 type of formula.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes this is intentional. I need to find a line that separates the two classes of datapoints. The datapoints are described as (x,y) coordinates, which are the two columns.

Comment: If you want to plot a line

Comment: The code you are using is fitting two models (one for each column of Data_Class2), each of which has _two_ independent variables (DataClass1) (and an intercept).  I don't think `lm` is the right choice for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking the same thing. I need to use `lm` though. So I think I should be somehow converting the data into just 1D data in that case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing statistical methods. Should be on CrossValidated.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is one way to go about it. Since you did not provide any data, we start by making some up. `mvrnorm(...)` generates a random sample from the multivariate normal distribution. Here, we pass a vector of length 2 as the mean, so we get bivariate normal. So `data.1` and `data.2` model what you have as `Data_Class1` and `Data_Class2`.

Since these are distinct by design, we combine them into a single data.frame using `rbind(...)` and add a classifier column `z` which has the value 1 for `data.1` and -1 for `data.2`. Now we fit a linear model of the form

> z = a + b × x<sub>1</sub> + c × x<sub>2</sub>

The boundary will occur at z=0, so we plot a line

> x<sub>2</sub> = (-a -b × x<sub>1</sub>)/c

Here's the code:

```
library(MASS)
data.1 <- mvrnorm(50,mu=c(0,0),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2))
data.2 <- mvrnorm(50,mu=c(3,3),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2))
plot(data.1, xlim=c(-3,5), ylim=c(-3,5), xlab="",ylab="")
points(data.2, col="red")

data.full <- data.frame(rbind(data.1,data.2))
data.full$z <- c(rep(1,50),rep(-1,50))
fit <- lm(z~X1 + X2,data.full)
coef <- coefficients(fit)
x    <- seq(-3,5,.1)
lines(x,(-coef[1]-coef[2]*x)/coef[3], lty=2, col="blue")
```

[image]